# Updating to Xcode 7 Beta 5 & Swift 2 produced multiple errors

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, xcode7-beta5

I updated Xcode to the new Xcode 7 beta 5. In doing so, it converted to Swift 2, but then created even more errors. Right now, I am completely stuck, and don't know what to do, because although all my errors are gone, my app will not work correctly.

My problem is this:

```
if(self.myOutput3 as? NSObject == true) {
        print("IT IS TRUE")

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(self.myOutput1 as! String, password: "xxx") { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                print("It Worked!")

                // self.presentViewController(destViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                let instillation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
                instillation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                instillation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toTimeline", sender: self)

            } else {

                // self.enterButton.enabled = false


                self.errorAlert()

                print("Couldn't log in...")


            }

        }

    } else  {
        print("IT IS FALSE")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("continueTheSignIn", sender: self)


       // self.move()

    }
```

The program will perform the *toTimeline* segue, but not the *continueTheSignIn* . I don't see any logical reason that this is not working. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Also, I am having an error in my messages feature.

```
cell.textView!.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:cell.textView!.textColor]
```

This is giving me the error "Cannot assign a value of type '[String : UIColor?]' to a value of type '[String: AnyObject]!'

I was not previously getting this error in Swift / Xcode 6.4, so I don't know how to fix it.

Additionally, once I bypass this to get into my app to see if my other features are working, most of my UITableViews are not displaying any information. One is, however the rest load the correct amount of rows, but display nothing. What could this be? Also, no Parse pictures are being displayed correctly either. These are even more concerning than the other problems...

Here is the picture after I deleted and re added the segue under a diff. name. 
[image]

Comment: You need a `!` after `textColor` for your compilation error (if you're certain that `textColor` has a value).

Comment: @zneak Okay, that fixed that error. Any thoughts on the others? (I just edited question to include another major one I just found)

Comment: the else statement is actually happening? I mean, the line `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("continueTheSignIn", sender: self)` is really executed?

Comment: @dGambit it gets to that line, and then doesn't execute it. However, if i replace that line with the same thing, except the other segue identifier, toTimeline, it works... I just don't get it.

Comment: delete and remake the segue, also try with CMD + Shift + K and then CMD + ALT + Shift + K accept the clean and delete the app from your device or simulator and try again

Comment: @dGambit I did this, and the problem still persists.

Comment: could you please edit the question and add a screenshot of the segue attributes inspector?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86848/discussion-between-anthony-saltarelli-and-dgambit).

Comment: perhaps you are missing the word Process??

Comment: @dGambit I always copy and paste from there! I am very baffled.

Comment: @dGambit No I am saying that I always copy and paste those words, so there is not spelling error from the storyboard to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Parse wont support the beta version . it needs a full version . I have contacted them based on a similar issue . They said they will update the parse to work with xcode7 once the full version of xcode7 is released.

Comment: On their blog they state: In order to prepare Parse to support iOS 9 apps, and to help our developers build more secure apps, we plan to upgrade the SSL certificate for https://api.parse.com to SHA-2 on Tuesday, August 11, 2015. I however, am still getting an ATS error because of the http vs https problem... I don't know how to fix this. Additionally, it will not download half of the content I need to display, in my UITableViews (even though they are not PFFiles)

Comment: All I can say is if you are learning then you can experiment with xcode7 beta if you are using it for production then you need to wait till full version arrives or switch back to xcode6.4 temporarily